# What is the last digit of the product of all odd three-digit numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please help. I can't seem to figure out how to get the answer

Comment: Take any number ending in 5. Multiply it by any other odd number. What's the last digit?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the first few 3 digit numbers to test out.

If we multiply 101 to 103, the last digit is 3

If we multiply that answer above to 105, the last digit is 5.

From here, because the last digit is 5, and we are going to multiply to any odd number, we are still going to get 5 as our last digit.